# Check a string if it contains a given substring and return BOOLEAN

Tags: haskell

I am trying to come up with a haskell function that takes 2 string parameters. Then it checks to see if the 1st string contains the second string as a substring. For instance: "bring" contains the substring "in". If passed "bring" "in", the function should return true. Here is what I have so far, but it doesn't really work. Works partially. I don't know how to assign a true value in the recursive cases.

```
check::[Char]->[Char]->Bool
check [][]              =False
check _[]               =False
check []_               =False
check(x:xs)(y:ys)
 | y==x                 =True
 | otherwise            =check xs (y:ys)

main = do
print $ check "bring" "in"
```

Comment: Do you have to write your own function for that? `Data.List`'s`isInfixOf` already provides this functionality (for lists that are instances of `Eq, not just for `String`s`).

Comment: yes. I do. Can not use libraries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A straight-forward implementation that does not use libraries or cool tricks at all could be:

```
substring :: String -> String -> Bool
substring (_:_) [] = False
substring xs ys
    | prefix xs ys = True
    | substring xs (tail ys) = True
    | otherwise = False

prefix :: String -> String -> Bool
prefix [] _ = True
prefix (_:_) [] = False
prefix (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x == y) && prefix xs ys
```

This is the "canonical" way for naive substring search (in any programming language I guess?): for every suffix of a string, you check if the substring is a prefix.

Note that the substring argument comes before the string.

Comment: Note that your argument order is flipped w.r.t. the question (but I favour this order).

Comment: @frasertweedale Yep, this was on purpose. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: xs marks the substring and ys marks the string I guess?

Comment: @RumenHristov At that point it should be obvious :) but yes

Comment: Use of `tail` causes empty list exception.

Comment: @frasertweedale yes, indeed. It should be correct now... is there a better way to do it? (Haskell is not my greatest strength :) )

Comment: this is interesting. I learned something, I guess I can call obvious but not so apparant at the same time. Just testing a few things and then will give credit.

Comment: this always produces "False"

Comment: @RumenHristov Not on my computer.... `*Main> substring "in" "bring"
True`

Comment: My bad. I had the order of the arguments backwards.

Comment: I'd use `substring xs ys = prefix xs ys || substring xs (tail ys)` for the last case.

Comment: @chi The last case of what do you exactly mean?

Comment: In the definition of `substring` there's a first case `substring (x:xs) [] = False`, and a second case for the rest.

Answer (score 3):

Reason it is not working is because you only seem to be matching on the first character of the second string:

```
check::[Char]->[Char]->Bool
check [][]              =False
check _[]               =False
check []_               =False
check(x:xs)(y:ys)
 | y == x               =True -- this line
 | otherwise            =check xs (y:ys)

main = do
print $ check "bring" "in"
```

Fix it by doing:

```
check::[Char]->[Char]->Bool
check l s = check' l s True where
    check' _ [] h          = True
    check' [] _ h          = False
    check' (x:xs) (y:ys) h = (y == x && check' xs ys False) || (h && check' xs (y:ys) h)

main = do
print $ check "bring" "in"
```

Also note as previously pointed out that an empty string is a subset of itself and any non-empty string. The extra boolean is to quickly eliminate the current search and start at the substring again

Finally to be a good programmer, we can make this generic by doing this:

```
check::Eq a => [a]->[a]->Bool
check l s = check' l s True where
    check' _ [] h          = True
    check' [] _ h          = False
    check' (x:xs) (y:ys) h = (y == x && check' xs ys False) || (h && check' xs (y:ys) h)

main = do
print $ check "bring" "in"
```

Comment: Yaa, I know the base cases can be simplified a bit. That's how I had it at first, but then I chose to write them all out explicitly.

Comment: This works, but even now it doesn't really work as per specs, because it needs to only return true if the substring is included as it is in the original string. IE: check "the cat is gone" "tg" will result true because the g in gone follows the t in cat. However it should only come to true if "tg" appears exactly as that in the original string.